# Python: Funcion que elimina los datos de un contacto partir de su id en un archivo de TXT

Tags: python, archivo, diccionarios, txt, tuplas

He intentando de diferentes formas lograr eliminar la informacion de un contacto ,deberia ser algo asi:

En mi archivo de txt estaria (nombre,id,cel) todo pedido por teclado ,digamos

Maya

789

555555

Pepe

1234

111111

Al digitar el id por ejemplo 1234 la funcion deberia eliminarme las tres lineas de Pepe en el archivo

Este es el codigo:
Hay un menu:

```
def show_menu():
print("Menu Principal\n"+
        "1. Ver listado\n"+
        "2. Ver listado filtrado\n"+
        "3. Agregar beneficiario\n"+
        "4. Buscar beneficiario\n"+
        "5. Borrar beneficiario\n"+
        "6. Salir\n")
```

Ahora asi se esta añadiendo los beneficiarios:

```
def Add(agenda,file_name):
    print("Digite la información del beneficiario a agregar:")
    nombre=input("")
    cedula=(input(""))
    celular=(input(""))

    lineas=[nombre,cedula,celular]
    lineas='\n'.join(str(sublista) for sublista in lineas)

    with open(file_name,'a') as archivo:
        archivo.write(lineas+"\n")
    print("El beneficiario ha sido agregado")
```

Ahora en la funcion del borrado

```
def Erase(agenda):
number= input("")
with open('Agenda.txt','r+') as f:
        d=f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)
        for linea in d:
            if  number in linea:
               del linea
            f.truncate()
```

Aca es donde se llama la funcion y los parametros

```
option=0
agenda= dict()
file_name= 'Agenda.txt'
Archivo(agenda,file_name)


while option !=6:
    option = int(input("Menu Principal\n"+
                      "1. Ver listado\n"+
                      "2. Ver listado filtrado\n"+
                      "3. Agregar beneficiario\n"+
                      "4. Buscar beneficiario\n"+
                      "5. Borrar beneficiario\n"+
                      "6. Salir\n"));
    if option == 1:
        Show(agenda)
    if option == 2:
        Filter(agenda)
    elif option == 3:
        Add(agenda,file_name)
    elif option == 4:
        Search(agenda)
    elif option == 5:
        Erase(agenda)
```

Ahora me elimina todas las lineas del archivo :(

Comment: Hay varias preguntas relacionadas al mismo tema, podrías buscar y guiarte

Comment: Seria más fácil si tuvieras toda la info del contacto en una sola línea, separando con coma los valores.

Comment: @CandidMoe osea que al momento de guardar los datos los pusiera tipo linea= "nombre,id,cel" ?

Comment: Exacto. Esa es la idea; dejarlos en formato CSV (comma separated values), que es un estándar sencillo para intercambio de información en formato texto.

Comment: @CandidMoe Lo cambie y ahora me quedo                                               
        nombre=input("")
        cedula=(input(""))
        celular=(input(""))
        lineas=[nombre,cedula,celular]
        lineas='\n'.join(str(sublista) for sublista in lineas)                                                                   pero no se como eliminar los datos :/

Comment: la palabra reservada `del` se utiliza para borrar un dato de la memoria

Comment: @Christian hmm en este caso que me recomendarias usar para eliminar los datos?

Comment: ya estoy haciendo una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace algunos días apareció una pregunta muy similar (por no decir igual), intente hacer una respuesta, pero mi código no funcionaba muy bien. Lo que hice ahora fue agrupar los datos (de una lista) en forma de tuplas de la forma `[(name,id,number)]` para luego poder buscar según un dato y luego poder eliminar todo.

Para ello primero se tiene que obtener todas las líneas en forma de lista, eso se hace con el método `.readlines()` luego usamos la notación de *slice* para poder iterar en un grupo reducido de elementos, en este caso iteraremos en los nombres haciendo `list[::3]`, esto indica que cogerá un dato saltando de 3 en 3.

```py
with open("Agenda.txt","r+") as f:
    info = f.readlines() #leemos todo
    #agrupamos en tuplas
    data = [ (d,info[info.index(d)+1],info[info.index(d)+2]) for d in info[::3]]
```

Como el slice nos devuelve el nombre tendremos que haya que posicion ocupa ese nombre dentro de la lista, eso lo hacemos con `info.index(d)` donde `d` es cada nombre, como sabemos que la información esta en el orden `nombre - id- cel` podemos decir que `info.index(d)+1` es la posición en la que se encontrará el dato de `id` y si le sumamos 1, obtendremos el `cel`. Para acceder a un dato de una lista se hace mediante si índice `info[x]` y como ya hemos obtenido el índice con `info.index(d)+1` solo hacemos `info[info.index(d)+1]` y lo mismo para obtener el celular pero le sumamos 2 `+2`.

Ahora tenemos que borrar la tupla cuyo valor sea igual al ingresado en el `input` (variable `number`), para eso tendremos que recorrer cada valor de la lista (tupla), y verificar su segundo valor que es donde se encuentra el `id`, si se encuentra utilizamos el método `remove()` para eliminar un elemento (según su valor).

```py
    ....
    #eliminamos
    [data.remove(id) for id in data if id[2].rsplit()[0]=="555555"] #se remplaza con la variable number--><<<o
    
    #truncamos el archivo
    f.truncate(0) #numero de bits a conservar
    f.seek(0)#nos movemos al inicio
    
    #juntamos los datos
    data = "".join("".join(dato[:]) for dato in data)
    f.write(data)#escribimos
```

Para este caso, le hemos pedido que borre los datos del usuario cuyo `id` sea `555555`, quedando el txt así.

```
Pepe
1234
111111
```

Comment: Pero solo funcionaria si yo digito el cel verdad?  osea en este caso si digitara el 789 no haria nada en el archivo,pero si digito el numero del cel si me lo elimina

Comment: si, pero lo que tu pides es el id, ósea esto funciona con el id, esto gracias al `if id[2]` ya que el id se encuentra siempre en el segundo lugar, si deseas cambiarlo por el cel solo colca 3 en vez de 2

Comment: Si,ya lo hice :3 ,Muchisimas Gracias enserio !

Comment: gracias a ti, como dije había un problema igual, al que no pude dar respuesta, pero tu me hiciste hallar una ^_^